# Water Heater cold water inlet pipes water directly into a drain?

Tags: water, drain, heater

I just moved into a home I recently purchased. One of the strange things is this with water heater

1. It makes a lot of noise
2. It drains water from the cold water inlet directly into a drain on the floor - (We've checked, there is water coming out of in - a good amount)

Does this make any sense? Could I just remove this pipe and cap it? (This makes sense to me, just don't want anything blowing up someway somehow)

[image: water outlet]

[image: drain]

Comment: Would not cap it until you know what that valve does/is for.  Could be the valve has failed and needs to be replaced.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for the heads up, we're leaning towards getting a plumber out here now. Thank you!

Comment: The white pvc pipe that feeds into the drain is typically coming from the pressure relief valve.  Does your hwt have hotwater output and cold water input on the top?  Can you take a picture of your prv?  Do you have an expansion tank?

Comment: It looks to me like that thin copper pipe is to allow you to drain the water supply lines should you ever need to do work between the water heater inlet and the next valve in the line. If there's _always_ water dripping out of it, the valve to this drain line is either not fully closed, or it's faulty.

Comment: You might try moving the valve back and forth to see if you can get it to stay closed.

Comment: You have a lot of bends in the vent, it may be advisable to re-do it and get rid of several of the 90s.